# Get data which is present in the column range of sheet4 but not present in listbox (listbox1) in listbox2

Tags: excel, vba

Am trying to compare a column range ("B2:B500") from sheet with listbox items and display items which are not in listbox. I want to copy the items which are not present in listbox1 but present in column range in sheet4 to another listbox i.e, listbox2. Someone please help me here

I will not be able to share data, but my code is as below which is giving considering only first item in a listbox1

```
Private Sub ListBox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)



'find last row

'LastRow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



'clear listbox

Me.ListBox2.Clear



'not just one value, but which ever were selected

For X = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

If Me.ListBox1.Selected(X) = True Then

'it is selected

curval = Me.ListBox1.List(X)

For Y = 2 To 1000

If curval <> Sheet4.Cells(Y, "b") Then

'found a match; populate listbox2

With ListBox2

.AddItem Sheet4.Cells(Y, "b")

.Font.Size = 8

End With

End If

Next Y



End If



Next X



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Populate List Box With Values Not Found in Another List Box

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ListBox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    
    ' Return the values from the column in a 2D one-based array.
    
    Dim Data()
    
    ' This simplification assumes at least 2 populated cells!
    With Sheet4
        Data = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
        
    ' Write the values from the 1st list box to the keys of a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict1 As Object: Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict1.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Item
    
    For Each Item In Me.ListBox1.List
        dict1(Item) = Empty
    Next Item
    
    ' Loop through the column data and if a value is not found in the keys
    ' of the dictionary, add it to the keys of a 2nd dictionary.
    
    Dim dict2 As Object: Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict2.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Item = Data(r, 1)
        If Not dict1.Exists(Item) Then
            dict2(Item) = Empty
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write the values from the keys of the 2nd dictionary to the 2nd list box.

    If dict2.Count > 0 Then
        Me.ListBox2.List = dict2.Keys
    Else
        Me.ListBox2.Clear
    End If

End Sub
```